# My profile has no email address. What is my Gravatar based on?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

The Gravatar URL uses an md5 hash of the lower-case email address.

So I'd expect my Gravatar to use MD5("")="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"

However, my Gravatar actually uses "dfc87203d5c57e2ad21acc178eead605".  Where does this value come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since February 2011, Stack Exchange uses a [salted hash of your IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122118/134300) as a fallback to generate your gravatar if no email has been specified.

---

It used to be an MD5 hash of your IP address. For example, if your IP was `127.0.0.1`, then its MD5 hash is `f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6` and your gravatar would be:

[image]

These unsalted hashes are still available in older database dumps.

Comment: Cheers, "dfc..." is indeed the md5 hash of my IP address in dot-decimal form.  Which kind of sucks.

Comment: @arx If it used an empty string then everyone without an email address would have the same Gravatar, whereas by using your IP address (or the one you used when you registered perhaps) then it's at least limiting the clashes to your network - If you supply or change your email address, it will update your Gravatar to use that.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I fully understand that, but I don't see any problem with users getting the same gravatar.  A modern GPU can calculate about 4 billion MD5 hashes of 15 character strings (i.e. basically the entire IP4 address space) in one second.  The current system is effectively publishing my IP address.  I'm not entirely happy with that.  I guess I'll set an email.

Comment: @arx in such case you might have a case to post feature request asking to not use your IP address or at least add warning about that so new users will be aware of the "risk". The system can use your unique Stack Exchange ID - for example yours is [110524](http://stackexchange.com/users/110524/arx)

Comment: @arx, you can use an e-mail address at `example.com` if you wish people to realize it's fake.

Comment: @msh210: Cheers, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: Looks like about 10% of gravatar hashes on SE are IPv4 based. (About 10000 total as of Jan 2011)

Comment: @arx The system is *not* publishing your IP address. If you can get your IP address back out of a one-way hash algorithm, please publish your methodology widely--you will be an overnight sensation in cryptographic circles!

Comment: @CodeGnome his point was that the IPv4 address space is finite and small enough for a modern computer to crunch. You can just md5 them all and create a database of hashes and all you need to do is a string match with your gravatar hash. If it's an IP, you'll get a hit, if not, it's an email based hash. The salt was added after this answer was posted (feature request by the same OP) and Jeremy banks edited that in.