# Use the user ID instead of IP address for anonymous user Gravatars

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, gravatar

[As I discovered yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122039/my-profile-has-no-email-address-what-is-my-gravatar-based-on), if you don't configure an email address your Gravatar is based on your IP address.  Specifically, SE calculates the MD5 hash of your IP address in dotted-decimal notation.

Reading some older posts on the internet (not specifically related to SE) it seems that the intention of this feature was to allows anonymous users to be identified without revealing their IP address.

This is a fail for a couple of reasons:

1. Users on SE are not anonymous, so the rationale for this feature is absent.
2. A modern GPU can calculate about 4 billion MD5 hashes of 15 character strings (i.e. basically the entire IP4 address space) in one second. The current system is effectively publishing the user's IP address.

**Please change the system so that, in the absence of an email address, Gravatars are based on a hash of the user's id number**.  This is public information anyway, so nothing is being revealed.

Comment: One disadvantage to this idea is that anonymous re-regs (so to speak) become slightly less obvious to normal users.

Comment: Publishing the IP of a user without explicitly telling him you do, is very bad style.

Comment: @Charles: Anyone who wants to "anonymously" re-register can set a bogus email address to change their gravatar.  This isn't a good excuse for leaking the IP addresses of average users.  At the very least this leakage should be made absolutely clear.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: You're BoltClock's a Unicorn; I'm arx.  These are probably not our "real" names (a vague concept anyway).  So what?  To clarify: by anonymous user I mean unregistered, or at least with no user ID publicly displayed.

Comment: @arx - my IP address also isn't my real name...

Comment: and if I really wanted to find somebody's IP address I'd just use an image on an external site and watch the logs, *far*, *far* easier than looking up 4 billion images!

Comment: @awoodland: With an external site, how would you know who the request was coming from?  And you don't have to look up four billion images.  You grab the md5 hash from the gravatar image url and reverse that.

Comment: "A modern GPU can calculate about 4 billion MD5 hashes of 15 character strings (i.e. basically the entire IP4 address space) in one second." Er, not sure I agree with that. My GPU was only able to perform 29.8M md5 hashes / sec.

Comment: Haha, I started writing a request that IPs be salted before I had to leave this morning. I get back, and there's a complete request waiting for me. It's like magic!

Answer (score 17):

I just added a salt to the IP address hashing, we have no user id to go by for anonymous users and still would like to keep stable gravatars.

This should keep stuff working just as it always did, with added security.

Comment: Now all of the anonymous users should have new Gravatars, right?

Comment: once deployed, yes

Comment: Thanks for that.  I didn't realise there were truly anonymous users.  What can you do on the site that doesn't require a login?  And how long is the salt?

Comment: I thought to post without logging in, you must enter an email? At least the field says "required". I assumed those email less users logged in, but from an OpenID provider that doesn't supply an email.

Comment: Using a salted IP address still allows people in the same house to discover each other's StackExchange accounts, because they will have the same hash. There is still a privacy issue. You really should use the user ID if there is one.